# Excel lookup function with two text conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would appreciate any advice on designing the right formula for my problem below.

I am trying to come up with a formula that would take into account multiple text conditions. Across the y axis I have 5 options; let's say America, Australia, Europe, Asia, and Africa. On the x axis I have Toyota, Lexus, Ford, Audi and BMW.

I need my formula to assign the outcome of "Critical", "High", "Medium", "Low", or "Negligible". So e.g. if "America" and "Toyota", it's "Negligible", if "Europe" and "BMW" it is "Critical", etc. With my options being 5x5 (x and y axis), I would need the formula to accommodate for 25 possible outcomes. I will have the outcome of x axis in one cell, and the outcome of y in another; the formula would need to check them both and state the decision.

What would be the right way of writing it?

Comment: What data do you have? Either you have a 5x5 grid and type the text in yourself, or you have some data you can base formulae on.

Comment: I made a grid where I typed the text myself. This will be used for qualitative risk assessment, so outcomes need to be tied to my heat map.

Comment: `=INDEX(matrix5x5;MATCH(country;column_header;0);MATCH(car;row_header;0))` ?

Comment: If you post a copiable table using [Markdown-Table-Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) it might help all of us to provide a solution. Showing what you have and what you need. Explanations always makes sense but a visual descriptions makes things more clearer.

Comment: Fair enough, here you go:

| Car/Country | Europe   | Asia   | Africa | America    | Australia  |
| ----------- | -------- | ------ | ------ | ---------- | ---------- |
| Ford        | Low      | Low    | Low    | Negligible | Negligible |
| BMW         | Medium   | Low    | Low    | Low        | Low        |
| Audi        | High     | Medium | Low    | Low        | Low        |
| Lexus       | High     | Medium | Medium | Medium     | Low        |
| Toyota      | Critical | High   | High   | Medium     | Medium     |

Comment: Please post here, not in comments. [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1834232/edit)

Comment: an alternative to index/match can be found here (something I always wanted to try but never found a use case): https://trumpexcel.com/intersect-operator-in-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Select the entire table
- `Formulas` => `Defined Names` => `Create from Selection` => Select both `Top Row` and `Left Column`

Enter the two parameters in some cell.

Then use this formula: *note the `space` between the two*

```
=INDIRECT(H9) INDIRECT(H10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I have been looking for. In my real-life table I have a a few multiple word headings (i.e. "Multiple locations in Europe" or "Single location in EU, US and AU") and the function does not work if the heading for that specific selection is longer than one word. Is it possible to fix it somehow, or?

Comment: @AlexK A `Defined Name` cannot have spaces. If you look at your list of names, you would see that Excel places underscores between the words. So all you need to do is the same. If you are manually entering the names in `H9` and `H10`, you can do that manually; or  you can nest a `SUBSTITUTE` function in the formula in `I9` to replace `space` with `underscore`.